# Laravel Feature Testing sqlite does not support Interval

Tags: laravel

I have a database query in my `postgresql` related to `interval`

```
where "posts"."created_at" >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days'
```

I am using a `SQLite database` for testing, but when running the tests, I am getting SQL errors related to the `INTERVAL` function, as `SQLite` does not support this functionality. What should I do in this case? What is the general practice when the `in-memory` testing database does not match the actual database?

I am running Laravel Feature Test in Laravel version 10.